# From Nested object gather children's value and assign to parent Property

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, javascript-objects

I have array of objects. All Objects and its children contain permission property array. I have to gather permission property values from children assign to corresponding parent. if multi children for  a parent permissions of parent should all children's Permissions.

```
const navItems: any[] = [
     {
      text: 'Analytics',
      imageUrl: '../assets/images/Qi-white.png',
      permissions: [],
      children: [
        {
          text: 'Reports',
          icon: 'layout',
          permissions: ['rep1'],
          route: 'reports/reports',
        },
        {
          text: 'NewSelectionPanel',
          icon: 'layout',
          permissions: ['rep2'],
          route: 'reports/reportsNew',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      text: 'Static Data',
      icon: 'parameters',
      permissions:[],
      children: [
        {
          text: 'Geographic Defs',
          permissions:[],
          maticon: 'settings',
          children: [
            {
              text: 'Country',
              maticon: 'grid_view',
              permissions: ['cou'],
              route: 'static-data/country',
            },
            {
              text: 'Country Allocation',
              maticon: 'grid_view',
              permissions: ['cou-allo'],
              route: 'static-data/group-to-country',
            } 
          ],
        },
        {
          text: 'Node Defs',
          maticon: 'settings',
          permissions:[],
          children: [
            {
              text: 'Node Category',
              maticon: 'grid_view',
              permissions: ['no1'],
              route: 'static-data/category',
            },
            {
              text: 'Node Class',
              maticon: 'grid_view',
              permissions: ['no2'],
              route: 'static-data/node-class',
            },
            {
              text: 'Node Classification',
              maticon: 'grid_view',
              permissions: ['no3'],
              route: 'static-data/classification',
            }
          
          ],
        },
        
        
      ],
      
    }
  ];
```

After gathering permission Is should be following structure

```
  const navItems: any[] = [
     {
      text: 'Analytics',
      imageUrl: '../assets/images/Qi-white.png',
      permissions: ['rep1','rep2'],
      children: [
        {
          text: 'Reports',
          icon: 'layout',
          permissions: ['rep1'],
          route: 'reports/reports',
        },
        {
          text: 'NewSelectionPanel',
          icon: 'layout',
          permissions: ['rep2'],
          route: 'reports/reportsNew',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      text: 'Static Data',
      icon: 'parameters',
      permissions:['cou-allo','cou','no1','no2','no3'],
      children: [
        {
          text: 'Geographic Defs',
          permissions:['cou-allo','cou'],
          maticon: 'settings',
          children: [
            {
              text: 'Country',
              maticon: 'grid_view',
              permissions: ['cou'],
              route: 'static-data/country',
            },
            {
              text: 'Country Allocation',
              maticon: 'grid_view',
              permissions: ['cou-allo'],
              route: 'static-data/group-to-country',
            } 
          ],
        },
        {
          text: 'Node Defs',
          maticon: 'settings',
          permissions:['no1','no2','no3'],
          children: [
            {
              text: 'Node Category',
              maticon: 'grid_view',
              permissions: ['no1'],
              route: 'static-data/category',
            },
            {
              text: 'Node Class',
              maticon: 'grid_view',
              permissions: ['no2'],
              route: 'static-data/node-class',
            },
            {
              text: 'Node Classification',
              maticon: 'grid_view',
              permissions: ['no3'],
              route: 'static-data/classification',
            }
          
          ],
        },
        
        
      ],
      
    }
     
  ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apparently want to mutate your object, which is blasphemy to the Gods of Immutability, Purity and Functional Programming.

On the other hand, since you're doomed no matter what, you can at least dispense with the ritual of duplicating everything and restricting JavaScript to a litany of chained array function.

Simple loops will do the trick nicely, without all this squandering of memory and CPU.

```
function GatherPermissions (input)
{
    function flatten_permissions (item) {
        // will merge two arrays and remove duplicates
/* If permissions are unique (i.e. you won't find the same permission in two different
   children) and you use that function wisely (i.e. you call it only once), then you don't
   need to enforce uniqueness and a simple "a.concat(b)" will be enough */
        function merge_unique (a, b) {
            return a.concat(b).filter((i, p, c) => c.indexOf(i) === p);
        }

        let flat_permissions = item.permissions ?? [];
        for (child of item.children ?? []) {
            flat_permissions = merge_unique (flat_permissions, flatten_permissions(child))
        }
        return item.permissions = flat_permissions; // mutation occurs there (booh!)
    }
    for (item of input) flatten_permissions(item);
}
```

Sample output using your input:

```
GatherPermissions (navItems);
console.log(`${JSON.stringify(navItems,undefined,4)}`);

[
    {
        "text": "Analytics",
        "imageUrl": "../assets/images/Qi-white.png",
        "permissions": [
            "rep1",
            "rep2"
        ],
        "children": [
            {
                "text": "Reports",
                "icon": "layout",
                "permissions": [
                    "rep1"
                ],
                "route": "reports/reports"
            },
            {
                "text": "NewSelectionPanel",
                "icon": "layout",
                "permissions": [
                    "rep2"
                ],
                "route": "reports/reportsNew"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "text": "Static Data",
        "icon": "parameters",
        "permissions": [
            "cou",
            "cou-allo",
            "no1",
            "no2",
            "no3"
        ],
        "children": [
            {
                "text": "Geographic Defs",
                "permissions": [
                    "cou",
                    "cou-allo"
                ],
                "maticon": "settings",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "text": "Country",
                        "maticon": "grid_view",
                        "permissions": [
                            "cou"
                        ],
                        "route": "static-data/country"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Country Allocation",
                        "maticon": "grid_view",
                        "permissions": [
                            "cou-allo"
                        ],
                        "route": "static-data/group-to-country"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "text": "Node Defs",
                "maticon": "settings",
                "permissions": [
                    "no1",
                    "no2",
                    "no3"
                ],
                "children": [
                    {
                        "text": "Node Category",
                        "maticon": "grid_view",
                        "permissions": [
                            "no1"
                        ],
                        "route": "static-data/category"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Node Class",
                        "maticon": "grid_view",
                        "permissions": [
                            "no2"
                        ],
                        "route": "static-data/node-class"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Node Classification",
                        "maticon": "grid_view",
                        "permissions": [
                            "no3"
                        ],
                        "route": "static-data/classification"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```